# Virtualenvironment Ubuntu 12 ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: django, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualbox

I can create a project with `django-admin.py startproject` within a virtualenv. But when I try to run server with `python manage.py runserver`, I get an error:

```
(check)robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/checking$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

But I can run the server when I deactivate the environment and run the it from the project directory. Please help how to solve this. Thank you.

```
(check)robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/checking$ pip freeze
argparse==1.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: please run `pip freeze` and paste the output

Comment: I have added the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, you have not installed django in the virtual environment.

- Either install django in virtual environment. Activate the environment and then install django using `pip` or other methods.
- Or link/copy django installed on the system (somewhere in `/usr/lib/python-XXX`) to python site packages in the environment. No recommended.

Comment: Yes, I think I just installed it in the virtual machine. And not in the virtualenv. Do I need to install in the virtualenv.

Comment: @Robin, yes, thats preferred way. You can instruct virtualenv to use python packages installed in the system as well. Check its documentation.

Comment: Ok. Can you please give me a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 5):

from the output of `pip freeze` you don't have `Django` installed in your virtual environment

run `pip install django`

Comment: Do I need to install django in all the environment that I create. I am just a windows guy, and a newbie in ubuntu...

Comment: yes, you need to install in all virtual environments if you are going to use it in the project, and this is actually quite useful as you can work on different projects with different django versions

Comment: Thank you much for the explanation and you help. Wish I could set both the answers as accepted. Anyways thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Django has lost some plugin with pip, so we can install Django with Tarball:

1. Go https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6.5/tarball/
2. Download Django-*.tar.gz
3. install it.

   > $ tar zxvf Django-1.6.5.tar.gz
   >
   > $ cd Django-1.6.5/
   >
   > $ python setup.py install