# Running Django in Virtualenv on EC2 -- ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, virtualenv, pip

I developed a django application locally, in a git repo. I launched an EC2 instance for the project and I set up a virtualenv with (what I believe to be) the correct packages/dependencies. I then proceeded to clone my repo into the virtualenv. Right now, I'm having difficulty as I'm receiving the following errors:

I attempted to use `python manage.py runserver example.com/8080` to test. I was sure to activate the virtualenv using `source bin/activate`, just like I did in my local virtualenv. When I call `... runserver` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Here is what `sudo pip freeze` produces:

```
Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
Cheetah==2.4.4
Django==1.5.2
Fabric==1.8.0
GnuPGInterface==0.3.2
Landscape-Client==12.05
M2Crypto==0.21.1
PAM==0.4.2
PyYAML==3.10
South==0.8.2
Twisted-Core==11.1.0
Twisted-Names==11.1.0
Twisted-Web==11.1.0
apt-xapian-index==0.44
argparse==1.2.1
boto==2.2.2
chardet==2.0.1
cloud-init==0.6.3
command-not-found==0.2.44
configobj==4.7.2
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
distribute==0.6.24dev-r0
django-s3-folder-storage==0.1
django-storages==1.1.8
django-tastypie==0.10.0
ecdsa==0.9
euca2ools==2.0.0
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.7.2
keyring==0.9.2
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.9.12
lazr.restfulclient==0.12.0
lazr.uri==1.0.3
medusa==0.5.4
meld3==0.6.5
oauth==1.0.1
paramiko==1.12.0
psycopg2==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.12
pycrypto==2.4.1
pycurl==7.19.0
pyserial==2.5
python-apt==0.8.3ubuntu7.1
python-dateutil==2.1
python-debian==0.1.21ubuntu1
simplejson==2.3.2
six==1.4.1
supervisor==3.0a8
ufw==0.31.1-1
unattended-upgrades==0.1
virtualenv==1.10.1
wadllib==1.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==3.6.1
```

...and this is my `./manage.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix this error? I tried to change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/var/www/paletto-env/bin python`, trying to direct it to my actual python path, but it did not lend to any apparent change, so I changed it back.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you copy the whole virtualenv tree to the EC2 instance, or did you create a new virtualenv and install the packages from there?

Comment: I created a new virtualenv and I installed the packages from there. Is not the best way to do it? Thanks

Comment: I've found that if the virtualenv is copied from another machine, it won't work; if I create a new virtualenv, install packages into it, _then_ copy my django project into it, then it works.  This may be worth a try but I don't really know the reasons - hence the comment rather than answer.

Comment: Okay, I just reread your question.  It appears you already did this.  Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're environment can't find Django, even though it's clearly in your pip freeze.

Try opening a Python (not Django) shell from your virtual environment and entering:

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

If you run into the same error, there's probably an issue with your Django install. Your virtual environment probably can't find it. You could try modifying the path settings, or just reinstall Django.

If you can successfully import Django, or if you tried reinstalling and it doesn't work, you may have a permission problem. Ensure that the user responsible for running the server has access to wherever your python libraries are stored from the virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

I had pretty much the exact same problem as you and this is how I solved it (Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this is the absolute correct way but it worked for me and everything seems correct).

### Short Answer:

Try `pip install (package)` instead of `sudo pip install (package)`

### Long Answer:

I gave the Django complete install doc ([See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/install/)) a quick read through and came across a bit that basically said you dont need super user privileges when using pip in the virtualenv. I just assumed that either would be fine but I now realize that's probably not the case.

I suspect that because I entered `sudo pip install django` it installed it somewhere above my local bin in my virtualenv for the project. I suspect this because when I enter `python manage.py runserver` I get an error; however, when I enter `sudo python manage.py runserver` everything functions properly.

Also, typing `sudo pip freeze` reveals my larger library whereas `pip freeze` reveals my local library for my virtualenv.

I didn't want to type `sudo (do stuff)` before everything and I wanted a nice, clean and proper virtualenv so I just reinstalled django but to my local virtual env with `pip install django` and now django is in the proper virtualenv library, `pip freeze` returns the proper contents, and `python manage.py runserver` functions properly!

Answer (score 1):

`django-admin.py startproject` by default creates the shebang in `manage.py` with `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

If this is not the path to your python executable, or if you use `python3`, just edit the `manage.py` to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall all python packages angain after you have **activated your virtualenv**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Django has lost some plugin with pip, so we can install Django with Tarball:

1. Go https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.6.5/tarball/
2. Download Django-*.tar.gz
3. install it.

   > $ tar zxvf Django-1.6.5.tar.gz
   >
   > $ cd Django-1.6.5/
   >
   > $ python setup.py install

more ... (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323774/686105