# Django's manage.py gives "no module named django.core.management"

Tags: python, django

The answers to the other questions about this error on StackOverflow are not resolving my problem.

From beginning, I type:

```
$ virtualenv ./env
 New python executable in ./env/bin/python2.7
 Also creating executable in ./env/bin/python
 Installing setuptools, pip...done.

$ source ./env/bin/activate

(env)$ pip install django
 Downloading/unpacking django
 Downloading Django-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.7MB): 6.7MB downloaded
 Installing collected packages: django
 Successfully installed django
 Cleaning up...

(env)$ django-admin.py startproject myproject

(env)$ cd myproject

(env)$ python manage.py syncdb
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
 ImportError: No module named django.core.management


(env)$ which python
 /home/twitch/Projects/env/bin/python

(env)$ python --version
 Python 2.7.6
```

Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19329290/2979912. It might be your case.

Comment: That's throwing "ImportError: No module named django". I've tried re-installing Python and virtualenv. This is all under an installation of Arch Linux from earlier today; everything else on the system is humming along perfectly.

Comment: Can you tell us what the shebang in `manage.py` is? It should look like `!#/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: @HuuNguyen It reads "#!/usr/bin/env python"

Comment: Do you get an error if you type `from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line` in an interactive Python session from your virtualenv?

Comment: @HuuNguyen Yes, ">>> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django.core.management"

Comment: Interesting. Tell me what `which django-admin.py` prints. You might've `pip install`ed Django in your global packages.

Comment: @HuuNguyen It shows pathway to the django-admin.py in the virtualenv: "/home/twitch/Projects/env/bin/django-admin.py"

Comment: @HuuNguyen It looks like another way to narrow this down is that its the specific machine I'm working on. I pushed this to github and pulled to my Mac, activated the virtualenv, and ran "python manage.py" without a problem. Now, what on Earth could I have done wrong with the Linux box? Bizarre.

Comment: @HuuNguyen Ignore that last comment, I should have verified using "which python"; its referencing the OS python install instead of the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

It's certanly a pip's install error of your django package. Try to downloading the django (version of your choice) source from the http://djangoproject.com site, and installing it directly through setup.py. Its really simple. With your virtualenv activated:

- Download the package
- Unzip on any folder
- On terminal, cd to the recently unziped folder
- run "python setup.py install" from that folder.

And thats it.

Comment: have you tried installing a different version on django? try "pip instal django==1.4"