# Python cannot find django after reinstall

Tags: python, django

I uninstalled django using pip uninstall django and reinstlled with pip.

When I execute startapp command after starting a new project, I get the following error. (It worked before I uninstalled django)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Django 1.7.1 is installed when I checked with pip freeze. But when I import django from python command line, it cannot see django. (I am using python 2.7.6)

Could anyone tell me how i can fix this?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380659/virtualenvironment-ubuntu-12-importerror-no-module-named-django-core-management)

Comment: How can I add django to python site package? Sorry, I am new to development, and just learning this.

Comment: are you using `virtualenv` or not?

Comment: Nope. Big problem is that you don't use [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Not using `virtualenv` is a problem but then the problem should not occur as `sudo pip install django` installs django system-wide (which is not so good) and so import works fine

Comment: I am not familiar with virtualenv... I don't understand why Django doesn't work any more after reinstall?

Comment: I used sudo pip install django, and it says django is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages